# Node.js TCP server delay in getting 'data' events from clients

Tags: node.js, typescript, tcp

I set up two TCP servers in Node.js with the native 'net' module. 
One is written in TypeScript and the other is in just plain JavaScript.

The plain JS one is performing as expected but the TS one is not receiving the 'data' event in real time. It looks like there is a delay between data events.

I've tried changing the target property in tsconfig but didn't make any difference.

This is the TS version

```
import { createServer, Socket } from 'net';
import GameConnection from './network/GameConnection';

class Server {
    public port: number;
    public clients: Socket[] = [];
    constructor(port: number) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    start(): this {
        createServer(socket => {
            const conn = new GameConnection(socket);
            console.log('client connected');

            this.clients.push(socket);

            socket.on('data', d => {
                conn.onData(d, d.byteOffset, d.byteLength);
            });

            socket.on('close', had_error => {
                if (had_error) {
                    //socket was closed due to an error
                }
                console.log('client socket closed');
                this.clients.splice(this.clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
            });
        })
            .on('error', err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
            .listen(this.port, () => {
                console.log('server bound');
            });

        return this;
    }
}

export default Server;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "strict": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and this is the JS version

```
const net = require('net');
const GameConnection = require('./network/GameConnection');

const server = net.createServer(c => {
    const conn = new GameConnection(c);
    console.log('client connected');

    c.on('data', d => {
        conn.onData(d, d.byteOffset, d.byteLength);
    });
});

server.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
});

server.listen(43332, () => {
    console.log('server bound');
});
```

When a client connects, it should fire exactly two events right away consecutively. The JS server receives both events fine but there's about 2-3 seconds delay between those events in the TS version of the server.

And even after the initial events, the TS server always seems to add a delay between receiving data.

Anyone with similar experiences?

Comment: Do you realize that you can look at the compiled TypeScript (which will be plain Javascript) and see what's different between that and your own plain Javascript version?

Comment: @jfriend00 yes I did have a look at the compiled JavaScript code but I couldn’t see any reason why it would affect delay/latency.